# Custom designing EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

I have custom designed `EditText`

[image]

**search_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#E1E1E1"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="City" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:layout_weight=".75" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**rounded_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

---

I want to use color code **`#2f6699`** to get a border color like an outline to the `EditText` text box as below:

[image]

**Any ideas on how to achieve this?**

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the below code in your **rounded_edittext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#2f6699" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="10dp"            
        />

</shape>
```

This should work

Comment: Stroke = border, Solid = background. I have no idea why Google reinvented the wheel.

Comment: I think only radius attribute is sufficient because you are using same radius in all four coeners

Answer (score 32):

[image]

For EditText in image above, You have to create two xml files in res-->drawable folder.
First will be "**bg_edittext_focused.xml**" paste the lines of code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#F6F6F6" />
        <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="7dip"
            android:left="7dip"
            android:right="7dip"
            android:top="7dip" />
    </shape>
```

Second file will be "**bg_edittext_normal.xml**" paste the lines of code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <solid android:color="#F6F6F6" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#F6F6F6" />
        <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="7dip"
            android:left="7dip"
            android:right="7dip"
            android:top="7dip" />
    </shape>
```

In res-->drawable folder create another xml file with name "**bg_edittext.xml**" that will call above mentioned code. paste the following lines of code below in bg_edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_edittext_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_edittext_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Finally in res-->layout-->example.xml file in your case wherever you created your editText 
you'll call bg_edittext.xml as background

```
   <EditText
    :::::
    :::::  
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"
    :::::
    :::::
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in your rounded_edittext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:thickness="0dp"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#2F6699"/>

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <gradient   android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear"
                android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="#E1E1E1" 
// background add in layout
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/button_color_submit" />
</shape>
```

use here

```
<EditText
 -----
 ------
 android:background="@drawable/edit_text.xml"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a [9-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or create a [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) drawable.

Comment: A shape drawable has a stroke too.  See the link I posted.