# Designing EditText with rounded corners & inner shadow

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to create a custom EditText that has both rounded corners and an inner shadow.

[image]

I made a layer list that creates the inner shadow,

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#6C6C6C" />           
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/ashes" />   
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:top="3px" android:left="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />           
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

The output looks like this,

[image]

How can I also add a rounded shape?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26015370/1352919

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `corners` tag inside your `shape` tags:

```
  <corners
      android:radius="5dp" />
```

Comment: Also, the previews might not show up in eclipse, so run the application.

Comment: I think it does not show up in eclipse only if there are different radius for each corner. Anyway it is worth to run the application to be sure ;)