# How to add drop shadow to textview with rounded corners?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-view

I am trying to add a drop shadow to a textview that has its background set to a drawable to give it rounded corners.
This is the effect I am trying to get:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_krkpxyd558NkhjMmdQZUdlc2c/view?usp=sharing

And this is how it currently looks:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_krkpxyd558UHE2YU5ENWhxWUE/view?usp=sharing

This is the current background set to the textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white"
         />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

I have seen other guides showing how to add a drop shadow to views by setting a custom background, but I can't seem to find a way of combining both a drop shadow and rounded corners.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check : http://belencruz.com/2012/12/rounded-button-with-shadow-in-android/

Comment: That was perfect, thanks. Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following links,

[Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow/21445593#21445593)

[Designing EditText with rounded corners & inner shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537517/designing-edittext-with-rounded-corners-inner-shadow)

This links surely helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
text shadow : 1px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```