# How can I set the width and colour of all the borders of EditText?

Tags: android

I have EditText. How can I set its border width and colour ***only*** and **in xml**? I can't figure it out and all I've found so far didn't explain that in a simple way. But I believe that so such a simple thing there must be a simple way to do it.

Comment: you have to try from this link its match with your requirement dear. https://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/

Comment: @VishalHalani, I need in xml.

Comment: @Steven you have to make like which jas posted using drawable

Comment: @Steven can you post your xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a drawable xml for your `EditText` with named `EditTextStyle.xml`  in your Drawable Folder like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />


</shape>
```

Change your color and width according to your requirement and add this as the background of your `EditText` of your Layout xml

```
android:background="@drawable/EditTextStyle"
```

Comment: why shape? why corner? why gradient? only colour and border width!

Comment: See the updated answer.Change the color and width accordingly

Comment: I already have this:

`<resources><style name="EditTextMyStyle"><item name="android:maxLines">1</item>.....`
How can I merge your code with mine? Should I create a new xml file? Then how can I apply 2 styles to a single EditBox?

Comment: @Steven you have to create this xml in drawable  folder and in your layout xml you can give in Edittext backgorund properties like following which jas posted

Comment: @Jas miss actually if i did not define where to make this then mostly android user understand  but for new in android its make confusion  you see that so i was edit. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough karma to say this as a comment. So typing as answer. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-a-edittext). Just create an xml file in drawable(here rounded_edittext.xml in the example) and set background for the `EditText` as

`android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"`

The `<stroke>` in the `rounded_edittext.xml` is used to set the thickness and color of the border of the `EditText`.

Here's the `rounded_edittext.xml` as shown in the link.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699" />

   <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"  
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: why would I need "corners android:topLeftRadius"?

Comment: @Steven you can just not use them if you don't want it. Use only the `<stroke>` to set color and width of the border. `topLeftRadius` is used for making the top left edge of the `EditText` curved like in the image in the link. You can see the If you want sharp corners, don't use the attribute `<corners>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create Customize editText xml in Drawable folder like

custom_edttext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#641E1E" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"

        />
</shape>
```

and use custom_edittext.xml as background of editText

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"/>
```

Comment: why would I need "corners android:topLeftRadius"?

Comment: If you do not want to rounded corner of editText then remove  <Corners/>

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer match with your needs.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#76b385" />

                <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <gradient
                    android:angle="-90"
                    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                    android:centerX="50%"
                    android:endColor="#ffffff"
                    android:startColor="#ededed"
                    android:type="linear" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Modify this xml with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

put this file in your drawable folder

edit_text_back.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
  <solid android:color="#00000000" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#641E1E" />
<corners
  android:radius="5dp" />


 </shape>
```

and add use this drawable as background to your edittext as

```
 <EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/edit_text_back"/>
```

If you need any assistance.Please let me know and mark this answer up.if it helps.Happy coding :)