# How to create a Custom SearchView?

Tags: android, xml, styles

```
  <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
        <item name="android:layout">@layout/custom_search_layout</item>
   </style>
```

I created this but don't know where to put that.
 I need to change the Underline of `SearchView` (is in toolbar) to an image.
 I don't no how to do that. please help me if anyone know how to do that or reference link would be great help.[any help to draw xml file like this image

[image]

Comment: What exactly do yo want to do? do you want to change background of `SearchView` or you just want to remove underline?

Comment: drawable image should be displayed in place of underline.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure.

`SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    try
    {
        Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchButton");
        searchField.setAccessible(true);
        ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView)searchField.get(mSearchView);
        searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_img);
        searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchPlate");
        searchField.setAccessible(true);
        LinearLayout searchPlate = (LinearLayout)searchField.get(mSearchView);
        ((ImageView)searchPlate.getChildAt(0)).setImageResource(R.drawable.search_img);
        searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_bkg); // set your custom background here
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

use this custom background drawable -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FE8059" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I've tested  and it works fine.

Comment: Image is covering whole SearchView Thank You, But i want to replace only underline with given image.

Comment: then why do't you use `setBackgroundDrawable` for custom drawable resource, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-a-edittext)

Comment: Please take a look on the attached picture, left and right strokes- only 25% of vertical lines should be displayed(left and right). i dont know how to make it. can we apply gradient to stroke?

Comment: @guessing - i've updated my answer. have a look & accept as correct answer if it works.

Comment: Thank you, See at left side and right side of the drawable its only 25% stroke from the bottom to up. I'm Sorry I cannot explain because of my English.   I thought of drawing another item on it but if i make the over drawing item transparent the background drawable will be visible.

Comment: You can simply achieve if you want the same in layout xml using `View` but you want to customize searchview that may not be possible. let me know if you want to apply on `EditText` in layout, which is easier.

Comment: @guessing try to use drawableLeft & drawableRight & use vertical view line with custom height. that will do the trick.