# how to make gradient stroke with transparent background android

Tags: android, xml

I want to create an EditText which will have a little transparent white background (about 30%) and gradient as a stroke, but i don't know how can i make gradient as a stroke color.
I try to do something like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E90Vt.png)

Could you help me in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this topic, its similiar like yours, you just have to make a custom edittext.

[Custom designing EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-a-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

I've already tryed to do this way, but in  i can't add gradient only pure color (ex. android:color="#000000"). 
I know how to make custom rounded EditText with transparent background, and i only want to know how could i use gradient instead of color in stroke ?