# How to change color of icon which is placed inside edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I am developing an application which has multiple form, but i want some effects on it. What i want to do is changing the color of icon which is placed inside `edit text`.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/marks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_border"
    android:hint="Total Marks"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: Can you share screen or image what exactly you want in `Edit Text icon`.

Comment: You can try to customize `EditText` as per your need. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-edittext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376610/

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTint`, `setTintMode` methods from the `DrawableCompat` class to set `tint` for `drawable` programmatically.

```
Drawable drawable = R.drawable.image; //Your drawable image
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GREEN); // Set whatever color you want
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

And after set the `drawable` for the `editText`:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

**EDIT 1:**

Make change in `Drawable` line as below.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done);
```

**EDIT 2**

Use `Focus Change Listener` of `Edit Text`.

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if(hasFocus){
         Drawable drawable = R.drawable.image; //Your drawable image
         drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
         DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GREEN); // Set whatever color you want
         DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
         editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
      }else { 
     }
    }
  });
```

Comment: getting error  incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable

Comment: @KritiJain check my **EDIT 1** in answer.

Comment: @KritiJain Can you please elaborate what is not working. And it's better if you share screen what you want.

Comment: I am having edittext and icon inside edittext, the icon is placed right side of edittext and its color is white. Now i want to change the color of icon when edittext is selected.

Comment: @KritiJain Follow my **EDIT 2** part using `on focus change listener` do all the code their .

Answer (score 1):

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_language"
                android:drawableTint="@color/gray"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Have you try "android:drawableTint" yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib: https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

Calling:

```
Icon.on(yourEditText).icon(R.mipmap.your_icon).position(Gravity.LEFT).color(R.color.youColor).put();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon);
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(d1);

DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_custom));

editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
Drawable d = mFriendsFeedButton.getCompoundDrawables()[0];

Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED);

editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(wrappedDrawable, null, null, null);
```