# Custom Background for editText in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

[image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
    android:width="1.5dp"
    android:color="#E53935"
        />

        </shape>
```

I want to make this type of custom design for editText.

Comment: Where is error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom designing EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189265/custom-designing-edittext)

Comment: There is no error. I just want to make the edit text a/c to the photo given above. My current code is not giving me actual design for the editText.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

[image]

> Your custom file is perfect just you need to use it in background of
>   edittext

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="User name"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_cust"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_cust"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

et_cust.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#c9837f"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Have you  checked the answer? is it working? you can aacept the answer like https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGNzO.png

Answer (score 3):

Use this for **EditText** as `android:background="@drawable/background_et"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 

    <stroke android:color="#FF0000"
        android:width="2dp"></stroke>

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

And this for button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 

    <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="0dp"></stroke>

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a Drawable file **custom_style.xml** into your  **Drawable** folder -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

And then use this as background to the EditText .

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your EditText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is set stroke to your background.!
 background_stroke.xml

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#E53935"/>
    </shape>
```

add this to xml:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background_stroke"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert your drawable as background in your xml file:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="0.2dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Set your background to edittext.

Answer (score 1):

As you created this xml for edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ED1C22" />

</shape>
```

now you need to use this xml into `EditText` background like this.

```
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
```

and you final activity xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
        android:hint="User name"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ED1C22"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```